Style the Price decimals and hide if .00
I have been trying to achieve the following, stylize the woocommerce price decimals (wrap them in a class) in order to make them superscript through CSS editing, but also hide/remove them in case they are .00
There are multiple solutions online unfortunately none seems to work effectively,
This is the closest I have managed to make it work:
add_filter( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', 'dcwd_superscript_wc_formatted_price', 10, 5 );
function dcwd_superscript_wc_formatted_price( $formatted_price, $price, $decimal_places, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator ) {
    // Leave prices unchanged in Dashboard.
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return $formatted_price;
    }

// Format units, including thousands separator if necessary.
$unit = number_format( intval( $price ), 0, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator );
// Format decimals, with leading zeros as necessary (e.g. for 2 decimals, 0 becomes 00, 3 becomes 03 etc).
$decimal = '';
$num_decimals = wc_get_price_decimals();
if ( $num_decimals ) {
    $decimal = sprintf( '%0'.$num_decimals.'d', round( ( $price - intval( $price ) ) * 100 ) );
}

return $unit . '<span class="decimalsev">' . $decimal_separator. $decimal . '</span>';
}


// Remove decimals if .00
add_filter( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', 'dcwd_remove_zero_decimals', 10, 5 );
function dcwd_remove_zero_decimals( $formatted_price, $price, $decimal_places, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator ) {
/*
    // Leave decimals in on single product page.
    if ( is_product() ) {
        return $formatted_price;
    }
*/ 

    if ( $price - intval( $price ) == 0 ) {
        // Format units, including thousands separator if necessary.
        return $unit = number_format( intval( $price ), 0, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator );
    }
    else {
        return $formatted_price;
    }
}

The issue with this is that when price is set inclusive of tax and there is a Tax set (in my case 23%) a price that should show as 4€ can show as 3.100€ (3€ and 100 cents), or 10 units of 4€ will show as 39.100€ (39€ and 100 cents)
Does anyone else suggest a better or different way to achieve this?
Thank you in advance for the attention and advice.

Sound like it is using more than two decimals internally - and with a price like 50.999, your "formula" of round( ( $price - intval( $price ) ) * 100 ) then will of course result in 100.

I would probably rather let WC format the price like it normally does, and then do some replacements on that result - simple str_replace to get rid of .00, if present, and a tiny regex replace to get a remaining .XY wrapped into an additional span - something like https://3v4l.org/SsGTd
